# Detecting if jQuery is already has a running instance

Tags: jquery

I'm making a script which requires jQuery X version. Let's say 1.7.1.

Script will be included into other systems like include('script-main.php'); as a plugin. I will just tell my customers to copy/paste it, because I have no direct access to their servers. It will be on sale on a website like eBay.

I need to know if they already loaded jQuery 1.4 in header, or another version.

So, how can I do a check like this? (in pseudo code)

```
if(jQuery->isLoaded())
{
     if(jQuery->getVersion() > 1.7)
     {
         //do my task
     }
     else
     {
         //include 1.7 but don't mess up already installed 1.4!
         //If they already have some jQuery coded in that page, it shouldn't break them - neither touch
     }
}
else
{
     jQuery->load(); //load 1.7.1 via googleapis
}
```

Comment: $().jquery; should return version

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
  // jQuery is not loaded  
} 
else 
{ 
  // jQuery is loaded
  var version = $().jquery;
  // Ex: "1.4.1"
}
```

Comment: What about using my jQuery without touching the old jQuery? I don't want conflicts.

Comment: This forum post discusses your options: http://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page